# Datos grabados desde puntero se borran solos

Tags: c, gcc

Esta pregunta es sobre C, punteros y gcc.
Mi programa escribe el numero 10 en 5 posiciones adyacentes a la dirección apuntada por la variable num. Aparentemente esos 10's se graban correctamente pero solo por un tiempo. Cuando hago el segundo FOR y trato de ver los valores de las posiciones antes grabadas ya no veo los 10's que había grabado. ¿Por qué? ¿Quien esta borrando esos 10's? ¿El recolector de basura?

## Codigo

```
void main( void ) {
  int num = 10;
  int *pnum = &num;

  for( int i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    pnum = pnum - 1;
    *pnum = 10;

    printf( "\n%p, %d", pnum, *pnum );
  }

  puts( "===========================" );

  int *p = &num;

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    p = p - 1;
    printf( "\n%p, %d", p, *p );
  }
}
```

## Output

> 0xffffcbec, 10
>   0xffffcbe8, 10
>   0xffffcbe4, 10
>   0xffffcbe0, 10
>   0xffffcbdc, 10
>   ===========================
>   0xffffcbec, 1
>   0xffffcbe8, -2146187872
>   0xffffcbe4, 0
>   0xffffcbe0, 0
>   0xffffcbdc, 0

Comment: Hola Fredy, gracias por traducirla, te sugiero leer [ask] para que realices tus pregutnas de acuerdo al [help] y sean bien recibidas :) .También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos!.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 10;
int *pnum = &num;
```

¿Dónde se encuentra `num`? ¿En la pila? ¿en alguna región específica de la memoria? ¿en un registro del sistema?

Bueno, supongamos que es en la pila... al hacer el primer bucle estarás sobreescribiendo posiciones de la pila que no le corresponden a la variable (pisarás memoria de otras variables de tu aplicación). Incluso es posible que intentes escribir fuera de la memoria asignada a tu aplicación y entonces será el Sistema Operativo el que mate tu aplicación para proteger la integridad de la memoria.

Ahora supongamos que se trata de una región de la memoria... el comportamiento será indeterminado dependiendo de las condiciones particulares de esa región de memoria... pero los resultados serán, en lineas generales, los mismos que en el caso de la pila.

Y ahora vamos a ponernos en el caso de que se trate de un registro del procesador... ¿A dónde apuntará entonces `pnum-1`? ¿A otro registro quizás?, ¿a una región de memoria? ¿...? En el caso de que apunte a otro registro será el propio ciclo de ejecución el que modifique esas variables pero no te quejes si empiezas a tener comportamientos erráticos.

Asi que bueno, resumiendo, **no hagas** esas cosas bajo ningún concepto. Trata las variables con respeto y cuidado. Si una variable no es un array o una estructura **no iteres** sobre ella (y esto último solo en contadas ocasiones, como por ejemplo al volcar su contenido a un fichero binario).

Comment: ¿Por qué preguntas dónde está num?, ¿no se supone que toda variable declarada dentro de una función (y main es una función) se graba dentro de la pila?

Comment: @FredyCuenca no necesariamente. El compilador sabe que no hay nada más rápido que los registros, luego si puede usarlos en vez de tirar de la pila no dudes de cual será la decisión final

Comment: @FredyCuenca eso sí, si la función llama a otra entonces sí que se verá obligado a volcar los registros a la pila para poder recuperar los valores cuando le vuelva el hilo de ejecución... pero en el caso de una función final es bastante probable que no llegue a usar nunca la pila si el número de variables vivas en cada momento es lo suficientemente pequeño